# Square root error in random walk

Tags: random-walk, mean-square-error

In Mazur and Stein's book, "Prime Numbers and the Riemann Hypothesis" there is a discussion about the square root error in a random walk (page 38). It says there that this quantity is $\sqrt{2/\pi}\sqrt{x}$. How is the coefficient $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ obtained?

**Edit** The comment answers the original question. A more interesting scenario, and the one I am interested in, is as follows. You have three possible moves: left, right, or no move at all (but time increments by one). We can assume the simplest probability scenario. Each possibility has probability 1/3. What is the square root error now?

Comment: There's a derivation here and references to further derivations: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html

Comment: @Joriki Great, thanks. I guess I can close this question. If you post your comment, I can accept the answer. Otherwise maybe I remove the question after a while.

Comment: @Joriki I have added a follow up question, which is what I am ultimately interested in. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. What happens when you're not at a perfect square $n^2$? And how can the probability of taking any one step remain the same if larger steps become available with increasing $n$?

Comment: @Joriki Right, I have changed the follow up question.